# RabbitMQ - non durable queue

Tags: rabbitmq

how can I change the default behaviour which makes my queues durable? I want them to be non-durable. The queues are created in the runtime as a backend for websockets.
There is a default exchange defined which has durable feature set to TRUE. I played a bit with exchanges but could not make it work as I expect.

Comment: what language / library are you using? or do you want to do this from the management web page?

Comment: I am using Java and Spring Websocket framework. It connects to the RabbitMQ using STOMP endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a queue using the Channel class, you can see those parameters:

```java
Queue.DeclareOk queueDeclare(String queue, boolean durable, boolean exclusive, boolean autoDelete,
                             Map<String, Object> arguments) throws IOException;
```

I am using:

```
'amqp-client:3.5.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

typically, you just set "durable=false" in whatever library is declaring the queue.

for example,

python: `channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', durable=True)`

java: 
`boolean durable = true; channel.queueDeclare("hello", durable, false, false, null);`

you can find other language examples in the [worker queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) example on RabbitMQ.com

you should consult the documentation for the library you are using, though

Comment: I do not see a way to configure it in the library. There is an exchange defined: Exchange: (AMQP default) which has durable set to true. Alle the messages go through that exchange. The problem is that its properties cannot be changed I guess...